# The dropdown list is not working in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Please read all the information

I have a class :

```
public class Cars
{
   public int id{get; set;}
   public string name{get; set;}
}
```

In addition I pass the data from database using stored procedure in my controller method as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   db = new CarEntities();
   var listOfCars = (from o in db.Get_Car_List()
                 select new Get_Car_List_Result
                 {
                     id = o.id,
                     name = o.name
                 }).ToList<Get_Car_List_Result>();

   return View(listOfCars);
}
```

In Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Cars.Models.Get_Car_List_Result>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }

<div style="align-content:center;">
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
      <p>My Caseload:
         @Html.DropDownList("CaseType", new SelectList(Model.ToList(), "Site_cd","Sitename"))
         <input type="submit" value="Find" />
      </p>
   }
</div>
```

I need to retrieve the data from drop down list into:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string CaseType)
{
   db = new CarEntities();

   var car_id= from o in db.Get_CarSites()
        where o.name== CaseType
        select o.id;                        
   //then run another query
   return View();'
}
```

Comment: Change Site_cd and Sitename to id and name respectively in your dropdown

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

1) Change `Site_cd` and `Sitename` to `id` and `name` respectively in your dropdown helper since those are the names that you are using in model:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CaseType", new SelectList(Model.ToList(), "id","name"))
```

2) Create a view model and use DropDownListFor helper:

```
public class CarsViewModel
{
     public int SelectedCarId {get;set;}
     public IList<SelectListItem> Cars {get;set;}
}
```

View:

```
@model CarsViewModel

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }

<div style="align-content:center;">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>My Caseload:
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedCarId, Model.Cars )
  <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</p>
}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    db = new CarEntities();
    var model = new CarsViewModel
    {
        Cars = db.Get_Car_List().Select(c=> new SelectListItem
                {
                   Value = c.id.ToString(),
                   Text = c.name
                }).ToList()
    };

    return View(model);
 }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CarsViewModel model)
{
    db = new CarEntities();

    var car_id= from o in db.Get_CarSites()
        where o.name == model.SelectedCarId
        select o.id;                        
    //then run another query
    'return View();'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Site_cd` to `id` and `Sitename` to `name` :

```
@Html.DropDownList("CaseType", new SelectList(Model.ToList(), "id","name"))
```